# Change admin form name for overridden User

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-2.2

I've overridden the standard django User by extending AbstractUser. Now this all works fine, but for some reason I can't make the admin display "Profiles" (the name of the model now set in settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of "Users".

[image]

This is my code for admin.py for the profiles app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

from .models import Profile


class ProfileChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = Profile

        verbose_name_plural = "Profile"


class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = ProfileChangeForm

    # fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + ((None, {"fields": ("some_extra_data",)}),)
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets


admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

I'd figured there should be some Meta setting I can put in here, but after significant amounts of googling I can't find anything.

I'm sure this is a simple answer - could somebody point me in the right direction? I've tried setting "name" and "verbose_name", but no joy. At the end of the day, I could live with this, as it's just the admin interface, but it's bugging me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `verbose_name_plural` setting im **model** class not in form class:

```
 class Profile(AbstractUser):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        verbose_name_plural = "Profile"
```

Comment: Damnit! I knew it would be something stupidly simple :) Thanks!